# Test Lab could not create a test matrix because required permissions are not set. Please verify that required APIs are properly enabled

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I currently have firebase setup and working on my device, I make sure of the storage and real time database and they both work great!

I thought I'd give the robo test a go to see what it does as it mentioned I would not need to add anymore code. Although when attempting to run the robo test with just the default 1 device ( Nexus 5g 23 ) I get the following error:
[image]

Normally I would assume I need to go into firebase within Android Studio and setup the gradle to enable this type of testing but the only option I have is the following.

[image]

which leads me to the more standard type of testing. I do not believe this is necessary for the Robo lab testing from my understanding (although I may be incorrect).

What's going on how can I use the Robo test? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is probably refering to the APIs enabled for the Firebase project being used to run the tests.

The project selector is shown in the upper-left corner of the Firebase web console ([console.firebase.google.com](http://console.firebase.google.com)). All of the required APIs are supposed to be enabled when a Firebase project is first created, or when a Google Cloud project is imported into Firebase. It is possible that one of the APIs was disabled or that this process didn't succeed.

Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=*your-project-id* and take a look at which APIs are enabled. Test Lab uses the "Google Cloud Testing API".

Here is the list of APIs that are enabled for one of the projects that I use for Test Lab.

[image]

Comment: Lol, I forgot I asked this question and re googled it and found "wow this is the perfect question for me" then I realised I wrote it and forgot! Thanks!